# Symfony4. Несколько подключений БД

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

делаю по мануалу
https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/multiple_entity_managers.html
не могу запустить стандартную авторизацию (по вот этому мануалу https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/guard_authentication.html#step-2-create-the-authenticator-class), там есть класс TokenAuthenticator, в котором я заменил 
`use App\Entity\User;` на `use App\Entity\Customer\User`
и при попытке залогиниться получаю ошибку

```
The class 'App\Entity\Customer\User' was not found in the chain configured namespaces App\Entity\Main
```

откуда там нарисовалось App\Entity\Main и как это победить?

Comment: Покажите ваш файл `config/packages/doctrine.yaml`

Comment: какой конфиг? говорю же - по мануалу 1 в 1 скопирован, ссылку вон нажмите первую

Answer (score 0):

Все дело в том что называется auto mapping. Делаете вы вроде бы по мануалу, однако неймспейс вашей сущности, как вы и пишите, живет у другой папке.

Скорее всего ссылка ниже вам поможет.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22813300/symfony-error-the-class-xxx-was-not-found-in-the-chain-configured-namespaces-xxx

Comment: видел я эту ссылку, не помогает она. если я в конфиге доктрины меняю дефолтный entity manager, то всё работает прекрасно. собственно вопрос, как сменить подключение к бд в EntityManagerInterface,  `getRepository(User::class, 'customer')` не работает